# Hide tab by clicking the tab instead of clicking any part of the website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, tabs

I created a support tab on this page (the one on the right): 
http://test88.fccbet.com/

This is where I got the the tab slide out effect: http://www.building58.com/examples/tabSlideOut.html

Right now the main tab hides if you click to any part of the webpage. What js should I add so it will only hide if I click the side tab?

Please refer to this image to know the main tab and side tab.
echosantos.com/tabslideout/tab-desired-outcome.jpg

These are the codes I used for this support tab:

HTML:

```
<div id="bannerLeft">
<div class="slide-out-div no-phone no-phone-landscape" style="background-image:url(images/support-tab.png); "><br />
<a href="javascript:supportPop('https://messenger.providesupport.com/messenger/043ddykhqw98l0mslsguhu8w79.html');" id="range-logo">Fccbet</a>
<a class="handle" href="#"></a><div id="close-bottom"><img src="@routes.Assets.at("images/close-chat.jpg")"/>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.slide-out-div {
width: 125px; 
height:392px;
background: url(../images/support-tab.png); }


#range-logo {
background-image:url(../images/support-tab.png);
display:block;
text-indent:-9999px;
width: 125px; 
height:396px;}
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
$(function () { 

$('.slide-out-div').tabSlideOut({
    tabHandle: '.handle', //class of the element that will become your tab
    pathToTabImage: 'http://wpaoli.building58.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/09/contact_tab.gif', //path to the image for the tab //Optionally can be set using css
    imageHeight: '122px', //height of tab image           //Optionally can be set using css
    imageWidth: '40px', //width of tab image            //Optionally can be set using css
    tabLocation: 'left', //side of screen where tab lives, top, right, bottom, or left
    speed: 300, //speed of animation
    action: 'click', //options: 'click' or 'hover', action to trigger animation
    topPos: '200px', //position from the top/ use if tabLocation is left or right
    leftPos: '20px', //position from left/ use if tabLocation is bottom or top
    fixedPosition: false //options: true makes it stick(fixed position) on scroll
});


$('.slide-out-div > .handle').click();

});
```

Thanks in advance! Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking into the `jQuery.tabSlideOut` plugin code you can see here:

https://gist.github.com/katowulf/2655810#file-jquery-tabslideout-1-3-js-L164-L165

The `document` is listening to a click event hiding the menu in the callback.

```
     $(document).click(function(){
        slideIn();
     });
```

I would suggest removing this part of the code from the plugin if you do not want to use this feature.

If you think you may need this feature in the future you can wrap a flag around it by adding a property to `callerSettings` parameter that is passed in when you initialize the plugin.

```
  var settings = $.extend({
     tabHandle: '.handle',
     speed: 300,
     action: 'click',
     tabLocation: 'left',
     topPos: '200px',
     leftPos: '20px',
     fixedPosition: false,
     positioning: 'absolute',
     pathToTabImage: null,
     imageHeight: null,
     imageWidth: null,
     onLoadSlideOut: false,
     tabHandleOffset: 0,
     hideOnDocClick: true //new flag to check for doc click hide 
  }, callerSettings||{});
```

...

Then use the flag to check whether to add the listener or not:

```
if(settings.hideOnDocClick){
  $(document).click(function(){
     slideIn();
  });
}
```

....

And when you finally initialize the plugin you can set the flag to `false`:

```
$('.slide-out-div').tabSlideOut({
    tabHandle: '.handle', //class of the element that will become your tab
    pathToTabImage: 'http://wpaoli.building58.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/09/contact_tab.gif', //path to the image for the tab //Optionally can be set using css
    imageHeight: '122px', //height of tab image           //Optionally can be set using css
    imageWidth: '40px', //width of tab image            //Optionally can be set using css
    tabLocation: 'left', //side of screen where tab lives, top, right, bottom, or left
    speed: 300, //speed of animation
    action: 'click', //options: 'click' or 'hover', action to trigger animation
    topPos: '200px', //position from the top/ use if tabLocation is left or right
    leftPos: '20px', //position from left/ use if tabLocation is bottom or top
    fixedPosition: false, //options: true makes it stick(fixed position) on scroll
    hideOnDocClick: false //set flag to false - menu does NOT hide when user clicks on doc
});
```